# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' Error when using tensorflow GPU

Tags: tensorflow

At the beginning, I used tensorflow on CPU to run a model and got no issues. But later on I realized that I will have more data and using CPU will take too long so I switched to tensorflow on GPU. But when I run the model I get errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

(base) C:\Binary Classifier>
```

I have looked up many solutions and none of those can fix the errors. I have followed the instructions to install CUDA 9.0, CUDNN 7.0 and Visual Studio C++ Redistribution 2017. The only problem I can still think of is that I did not add VS C++ Redistribution 2017 into %PATH%. However, I can not find the directory which contains the file and so don't know what to add to the PATH(VS C++ Redistribution installer does not let me select which directory to install it). Does anyone know what to add to PATH? Or is there another solution to this issue?

Comment: Can you highlight the differences with the [question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438681/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal)?

Comment: I actually fixed the issue I posted yesterday by using $pip install tensorflow(I should've marked it as solved, sorry for not doing that). For this question, I now installed tensorflow on GPU, and can't fix it even though I use pip this time. In other words, I can still use tensorflow if I am ok with CPU but it doesn't work with GPU

Comment: Which version of tensorflow have you installed when you faced this problem? Have you managed to solve this problem yet?